# Why does Appium use platformName instead of platform

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

Selenium exposes a [PLATFORM](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/CapabilityType.html#PLATFORM) capability:

Appium's MobileCapabilityType extends Selenium's CapabilityType interface but instead of using the PLATFORM capability, it exposes [PLATFORM_NAME](http://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/remote/MobileCapabilityType.html#PLATFORM_NAME):

Tried searching why this is the case but couldn't find any explanation. Does anyone here know the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well that's not used Nowadays `PLATFORM_NAME` was used till appium java-client 1.7. From 2.0 it's just used internally

From [ReadME](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/9de5874a9fb2fc18b65c6fac5e2ace8651d315af/README.md)

> AppiumDriver is now an abstract class, use IOSDriver and AndroidDriver
>   which both extend it. You no longer need to include the PLATFORM_NAME
>   desired capability since it's automatic for each class. Thanks to
>   @TikhomirovSergey for all their work

And for why, they were using Selenium's Platform in the first version 1.3 but then everything changed in the 1.4 where they decide to make their own [capabilities](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/e6927c60e2264e32eade441dbfbf57f183310b43/docs/en/advanced-concepts/migrating-to-1-0.md) with the future of Appium in their mind

This is to avoid the conflict of using `MAC` platform to test on `iOS` devices

Coz Selenium provided only `ANDROID` and `MAC` as platforms and though you want to test on ios devices which runs on `iOS` and you have to set `MAC` as platform [which will be odd right]

Now you can have [Firefox](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/v3.1.0/src/main/java/io/appium/java_client/remote/MobilePlatform.java) as platformName as well

And Appium is a seperate entity from Selenium and they can't ask Selenium to add a Platform as IOS for them.So They created their own capability I guess.

Comment: OK that makes sense. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Wish this was in the docs. So do we still need `MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION`? My tests seem to be working fine without it.

Comment: PLATFORM_VERSION is probably the substitute for Selenium's VERSION.   Not required to use it unless you want to request the driver for a specific version. I haven't used it in my tests so far.